# Simplify and prettify function looking for max value in a list and modifying some underlying values within that list

Tags: java

This function is used to modify values in list `List<GoogleUsageMapping>` and prepare them for entering into billing system.

I'm hoping this function can be more simplified and prettified, logic works.
Function needs to keep track of `maxValue` and if the `maxValue` is of type `LOGICAL_SIZE`. Would love to eliminate one of the for-loop if possible for instance.

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    BigDecimal highestQuantity = new BigDecimal(0);
    GoogleUsageMapping recordHighestQuantity = null;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getQuantity().compareTo(highestQuantity) > 0) {
            highestQuantity = record.getUsage().getQuantity();
            recordHighestQuantity = record;
        }
    }

    if (recordHighestQuantity.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
        s_logger.info("Overage scenario accord LOGICAL_SIZE: " + recordHighestQuantity.getUsage().getQuantity() + " greater than ALLOCATED_SIZE");
        for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
            if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
                continue;
            }
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

modified version:

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    GoogleUsageMapping recordUsageHighestQuantity = Collections.max(records, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getUsage().getQuantity()));

    if (recordUsageHighestQuantity.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
        s_logger.info("Overage scenario accord LOGICAL_SIZE: " + recordUsageHighestQuantity.getUsage().getQuantity() + " greater than ALLOCATED_SIZE");
        for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
            if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
                continue;
            }
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you use this code? What library you are using for the input _GoogleUsageMapping_? The code you presented in its current form is not meaningfully reviewable. We require sufficient context to make a proper review. See [What topics can I ask about?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for reference.

Comment: @dfhwze added some more description as you pointed out.

Comment: Possible `NullPointerException` if given an empty list or a list with no records with a usage quantity greater than zero.  Perhaps that can never happen, but not possible to tell without greater context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of a for-loop just for code clarity, you could use a `Stream` and the `max()` function. (Assuming you're using Java 8+). You could also use Streams for the second for-loop.

Note however, it's not logically possible to avoid iterating through the list twice. You have to check every element to get the largest value, and again to set values on every item in the list.

I don't see you using `highestQuantity`, it's not really necessary since you have a pointer to `recordHighestQuantity` already.

Comment: good pointers, will take a look at it, thank you